File 'root/lib/arm64-v8a/include/cblas.h' uses reserved file or directory name 'lib'. Error when building flutter appbundle
I'm working on a flutter application and we are using deeplearning4j. When running flutter build appbundle I am faced with the following error
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageReleaseBundle'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.PackageBundleTask$BundleToolWorkAction
   > File 'root/lib/arm64-v8a/include/cblas.h' uses reserved file or directory name 'lib'.

flutter build appbundle --verbose leads to the following error
 Resolve mutations for :app:packageReleaseBundle (Thread[included builds,5,main]) started.
[        ] :app:packageReleaseBundle (Thread[Execution worker Thread 11,5,main]) started.
[        ] > Task :app:packageReleaseBundle FAILED
[        ] Caching disabled for task ':app:packageReleaseBundle' because:
[        ]   Build cache is disabled
[        ] Task ':app:packageReleaseBundle' is not up-to-date because:
[        ]   Task has failed previously.
[        ] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[   +1 ms] * What went wrong:
[        ] Execution failed for task ':app:packageReleaseBundle'.
[        ] > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.PackageBundleTask$BundleToolWorkAction
[        ]    > File 'root/lib/arm64-v8a/include/cblas.h' uses reserved file or directory name 'lib'.
[        ] * Try:
[        ] > Run with --debug option to get more log output.
[        ] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
[        ] * Exception is:
[        ] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:packageReleaseBundle'.
...

Sources I have looked at but could not use any of them to solve my problem:
https://community.konduit.ai/t/flutter-android-appbundle-issues-with-dl4j/3242/3
"Uses reserved file or directory name 'lib'" error when trying to build android app bundle
